# Minimum of $x^2+8x+\frac{64}{x^3}$ for positive real $x$

Tags: inequality, optimization, contest-math, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Let $x$ be positive real number. Find the minimum value of $x^2+8x+\frac{64}{x^3}$.

I'm practicing some problems for a contest and this is one of them. Since most of the high school contests don't allow using calculus, I want to solve this without using calculus.

The problem looks obvious by AM-GM as $$x^2+8x+\frac{64}{x^3}\geq 3\sqrt[3]{8\cdot 64}=24$$
However, there is no $x$ for which $x^2=8x=\frac{64}{x^3}$ and thus this is not a minimum.

So how to deal with this problem?

Comment: [AOPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h565453p3307444)

Comment: Hint: In order to apply AMGM, you will need all of the terms to be equal. As you realized, the naive version isn't possible, which means that to pursue AM-GM you will need to (guess how to) weight the terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use inequalities to find minima, we need the equality condition to be satisfied as well, hence in this case we need $x^2=8x=\frac{32}x$, which doesn't have a solution.

If you have a "lucky guess" for which $x$ the minimum occurs (*and you know you have the minimum value somehow*), we can split the terms to equal components and then apply AM-GM.  If not, there is still a way - consider the more general version:

$$x^2 + \alpha \; \frac{8x}\alpha + \beta\; \frac{64}{\beta x^3} \geqslant (1+\alpha+\beta) \left(x^2\cdot \left(\frac{8x}\alpha\right)^\alpha \cdot \left( \frac{64}{\beta x^3}\right)^\beta\right)^{\frac1{1+\alpha+\beta}} \tag{1}$$
*While it is not necessary to write the above inequality out, I am reproducing it for clarity.*

Now for using this inequality for minimum, the RHS must be a constant, i.e. $x-$free, so we need $\alpha = 3\beta-2$ considering the exponents of $x$.

Further, for the equality condition we must have some $x$ for which
$$x^2 = \frac{8x}\alpha = \frac{64}{\beta x^3} \iff x = \frac{8}{3\beta-2}  = \frac{64(3\beta-2)^4}{\beta \cdot 8^4}$$
The last equality gives $(3\beta-2)^5=2^9\beta$ which can be solved (*well, by observation, or trying one's luck at rational roots*) for $\beta=2$.  After doing all that, you can write out ($1$) with the correct $\alpha, \beta$ values for the desired AM-GM.

Comment: Thanks, I needed this kind of which explains why to choose a certain set of coefficients in AM-GM (+1). Just for a bit clarification- You added coefficients $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with $8x$ and $\frac{64}{x^3}$, but why not add another coefficient before $x^2$? In other words, how do you know that the coefficient of $x^2$ would be $1$??

Comment: Scaling all terms by the same factor doesn't affect anything in the inequality.  What matters is the ratio of the terms, so you can always assume one of the coefficients is $1$. In some problems assuming the sum of coefficients is $1$ is simpler, ie they are weights, depends on the context.

Answer (score 3):

you can write the sum as $$ x^2 + 4 * 2x + 2* \dfrac{32}{x^3} $$